# Boolean and Conditionals

Tags: python, boolean

I'm currently working my way through Codecademy and have come to the final lesson in the Python "conditionals and Control Flow". It asks for the following code to return true, but when I try to submit this it outputs "none". What am I doing wrong?

```
def the_flying_circus():

    if 5 == 5:
        print "True"
    elif not True:
        print "False"
    else:
        print "something else"
```

Comment: You haven't returned anything.

Comment: NOTE, the default behaviour of a method with no return value specified is to return None.

Comment: Also, `True is not "True"`.

Comment: You have no `return` statement, just `print`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "print" statements by "return". That should do it.

Comment: That did it. In the example for conditional statements it used print so I did the same but changing them to return worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now that the answer is obvious, I would suggest to do this instead

```
def the_flying_circus():
   return 5 == 5
```

Thanks to the Python developers, `==` returns `True` and `False` automatically

Or as JonB mentioned [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610007/boolean-and-conditionals/27610087#comment43642494_27610087), We can rather hard-code the value

```
def the_flying_circus():
   return True
```

As `5` is always equal to `5` No matter what happens on earth.

Comment: Aside from the nonsensical nature of the question the corrected version would be (assuming it's blackboxed anyway):  `def the_flying_circus(): return True`

Comment: @JonB Do check this [tweet](https://twitter.com/mariofusco/status/542278747941261313)

Comment: I think that the spirit of that tweet favors @JonB's comment. `5 == 5` is logically identical to `True`, so just return `True`.

Comment: @JonB Added your comment to my answer !

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the nonsensical nature of the question the corrected version would be (assuming it's blackboxed anyway):

```
def the_flying_circus():
    return True
```

But in the spirit of meeting CodeAcademy's requirement:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if 5 == 5:
        return True
    elif not 5 == 5:
        return False
    else:
        return "Dumb exercise"
```

Comment: I checked the CodeAcademy question, and it says: "Write an if statement in the_flying_circus(). It must include: if, elif, and else statements; At least one of and, or, or not; A comparator (==, !=, <, <=, >, or >=); Finally, the_flying_circus() must return True when evaluated." All of this in a function accepting no arguments, and which has no clear purpose. It's a pointless excercise, if you ask me... Anyways, point is, `def the_flying_circus(): return True` is rejected by CodeAcademy because it doesn't meet the above criteria.

Comment: No accounting for teaching poor programming practices.  Does not conform to [The Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).  The other answers saying to replace `print` with `return` and the strings `'True'` and `'False`' with the boolean `True` and `False` are the _correct_ answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `print` to `return` and remove the quotes on the `True` and `False`.